# Excel formula to check date within this week and last week

Tags: excel, date

Does anyone know an excel formula in which if the dates are within this week (Todays date) for the cells to read the text “this week” and if the dates are from the last week for the cells to read “last week”.

Ps: If the formula could also read "old" if the date range is not with this week or last week

Example: Column A has the following dates. I want column b to read whether or not the date is within this week or last week from today’s date.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 01/11/2013 | Old |
| 02/11/2013 | Old |
| 03/11/2013 | Old |
| 04/11/2013 | Old |
| 05/11/2013 | Old |
| 06/11/2013 | Old |
| 07/11/2013 | Old |
| 08/11/2013 | Old |
| 09/11/2013 | Old |
| 10/11/2013 | Old |
| 11/11/2013 | Old |
| 12/11/2013 | Old |
| 13/11/2013 | Old |
| 14/11/2013 | Last week |
| 15/11/2013 | Last week |
| 16/11/2013 | Last week |
| 17/11/2013 | Last week |
| 18/11/2013 | Last week |
| 19/11/2013 | Last week |
| 20/11/2013 | Last week |
| 21/11/2013 | This Week |
| 22/11/2013 | This Week |
| 23/11/2013 | This Week |
| 24/11/2013 | This Week |
| 25/11/2013 | This Week |
| 26/11/2013 | This Week |
| 27/11/2013 | This Week |
| 28/11/2013 | This Week |

Big thanks to anyone who can solve this please.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: According to your list 21st Nov up to 28th Nov are all "this week" - that's 8 days, should it be 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming first date in `A2` try this formula in `B2` copied down to give those results:

```vb
=IF(A2 < TODAY()-14, "Old", IF(A2 < TODAY()-7, "Last week", "This Week"))
```

....but as per my comment that puts 8 days in current week, is that right? If not then change both `<` to `<=`.

Comment: Thanks very for all responses. I went with barry Houdini answer it was a great formula for me to understand as I am new to excel. Works great. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the difference between the week numbers.

| Diff | Output |
| --- | --- |
| = 0 | This week |
| = 1 | Last week |
| >= 2 | Old |

Excel formula :

```vb
=if( (WEEKNUM(now()) - WEEKNUM(A1)) < 0,
     "Future",
     if( (WEEKNUM(now()) - WEEKNUM(A1)) = 0, 
          "This Week", 
          if( (WEEKNUM(now()) - WEEKNUM(A1)) = 1,
               "Last Week",
               "Old"
            )
       )
   )
```

Comment: this may fail at week 0 when you compare two dates from different years

Comment: Here is an example of checking the year for only "This week" (`✔`), `=IF(AND(YEAR(TODAY())=YEAR($A2),WEEKNUM(TODAY())=WEEKNUM($A2)),"✔","-")`