# Check if date is within five working days

Tags: excel

I want to create a formula in Excel to check if a date is within five working days of today().

```
=IF(H6<TODAY()-14,"Old",IF(H6<TODAY()-7,"last week", "This Week"))
```

If the date is within five working days then show 'this week', otherwise if the date was last week show 'last week' or if older show 'older'.

This works on a seven day assumption, but how can I get it to work for a five working day week?

Comment: I'm not quite clear - if today is Monday 21st September, would you regard Friday 18th September as being in the current week because it is less than five working days ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well OK you can use NETWORKDAYS to see how many working days a certain date is before today, but when TODAY is a weekday it gave the same answer as your formula (almost - yours is inclusive so includes last Monday, mine doesn't):-

```
=IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY())>10,"Old",IF(NETWORKDAYS(A2,TODAY())>5,"Last week","This week"))
```

TODAY at time of writing was 21st September 2015.

NETWORKDAYS really comes into its own if you want to omit public holidays.

If you just want to see if a day is in the same week as today, use WEEKNUM:-

```
=IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A2)>1,"Old",IF(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-WEEKNUM(A2)>0,"Last week","This Week"))
```

The default with WEEKNUM is to start the week on Sunday, but this can be changed.

I'll put the three formulae together so you can compare them.

[image]

Comment: Eagle-eyed people may have noticed that my WEEKNUM formula (column E) wouldn't work across a year boundary so that isn't a good way to do it but column D is the main point of the question and that should be fine because NETWORKDAYS will handle it correctly.

Comment: Maybe I should re-visit this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266475/excel-formula-to-check-date-within-this-week-and-last-week (starting to look like a duplicate!) but I would prefer to go back to first principles and use =INT((A2-1)/7) [Since dates start at Sunday 1/1/1900] rather than WEEKNUM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the date in `H6`, use formula:

```
= AND(H6>=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5),H6<=WORKDAY(TODAY(),5),WEEKDAY(H6)<6)
```

See how it works as of `TODAY() = 2015-09-21`:

[image]

If you want weekend days which are within range **included**, then use formula

```
= AND(H6>=WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5),H6<=WORKDAY(TODAY(),5))
```

[image]

Comment: @Markharris – answer updated - is it easier-to-use now?